Как получить пользователя нажавшего на кнопку?
я отправляю правила в эмбеде командой, в эмбеде есть кнопка которая должна во-первых выдавать роль(channel('rul')(это моя функция)) и отправляю ответ, видимый только тому кто нажал на кнопку:
@commands.slash_command(name='правила', description='отправляет правила')
@commands.is_owner()
async def json(inter):
    def agree(self, inter):
    embeds = []
    for f in load(open('./cogs/rules.json', encoding='utf-8'))['embeds']:
        embeds.append(disnake.Embed.from_dict(f))
    content = ("**Находиться здесь — это привилегия не всем доступная, а не право. Соблюдайте правила сервера и [Di"
               "scord ToS](https://discord.com/terms), не грубите другим участникам и не создавайте проблем, котор"
               "ых можно избежать.**")
    components = disnake.ui.ActionRow()
    button = disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, label='Согласиться в правилами', emoji='✅')
    components.append_item(button)
    await channel('rul').send(content=content, embeds=embeds, components=components)

но я незнаю как это сделать
